# asp.net error retrieving from database when query string contains number

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, dataset, query-string, request.querystring

i am using a dataset to retrieve some info from the database like this:

```
    protected DataSet getInfo() //getting the user info
{
    string id = Request.QueryString["User"];

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM copy WHERE id=@id", conn());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);

    return ds;
}

   cvPage.InnerHtml = getInfo().Tables[0].Rows[0]["cv"].ToString();
   clPage.InnerHtml = getInfo().Tables[0].Rows[0]["cl"].ToString();
   bioPage.InnerHtml = getInfo().Tables[0].Rows[0]["bio"].ToString();
```

and it works fine until there is a number in the query string so if:

```
QueryString["User"] = "111111"
```

i will get an incorrect syntax error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '111111'.
```

but if there is no numbers it will work fine.

my database contains four columns:

```
id | varchar
cv | nvarchar
cl | nvarchar
bio | nvarchar
```

i am using asp.net 4.0.

what is the problem?

thanks

Comment: Do you really need `id` to be a `varchar`?

Comment: Use sql servedr profiler to see what's the exact query that is being executed behind the scene .

Comment: @AbeMiessler - yes it must be a varchar. but i already tried CAST as int and didn't work.

Comment: I agree with @AbeMiessler.  Otherwise you could convert the integer "1111" into a varchar in your select statement.

Comment: @ChristopherRathermel - i already tried CAST and CONVERT but didn't work.

Comment: @Beatles1692 - unfortunately i don't have access to the server profiler as i am using Express Edition

Comment: `Incorrect syntax near '111111'` can't be coming from that code.

Comment: @MartinSmith - when i try the code in sql server it works fine, and this code will work fine with non-numeric query strings

Comment: @Wahtever - I think you are looking at the wrong bit of your `C#` code. It must be sending a string to SQL Server containing the literal `11111` to get that error message but you are showing a parameterised query. Double check the line number in the error message. Also is your code **exactly** the same as what you posted or have you changed anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM copy WHERE id= CONVERT(varchar(4000), @id) ", conn());
```

Comment: yes same error "Incorrect syntax near '111111'" but when i try to convert to int i get this error instead `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '.....Website.com/Shatha' to data type int`

Comment: OK, another approach, try dealing with it on db-side. Change 4000 with something other if you want, ideally with number on column definition.

Comment: yes thank you, works great. just a quick question can a table name contain numbers like table 12eight. thank you

Comment: @Wahtever - I guess you were doing something like `"SELECT * FROM " + id + "copy WHERE id=@id"` then?

Comment: @MartinSmith - its actually something iam trying to do, and i wanted to know if it's possible.

Comment: @Wahtever - The code you posted cannot cause the error you say you were getting. You must be concatenating the literal value into the query somewhere.

Comment: @MartinSmith - i really which i could understand what happened, maybe it was a database problem at the time. i will try to revert back to the original code in a couple of days and see if it works.

Comment: @Wahtever - In answer to your other question, yes object names can contain numbers but must be delimited with `[]` if they start with a number. e.g. `[123foo]`. Watch out for SQL injection.

Comment: @MartinSmith - thank you. and i will try to identify the problem, once i do i will post it here. thank you again.

Comment: @MartinSmith - you were right, it was the url rewriting system. it was going to another page executing a differnt sql without changing the url and by the time i tried the last code they got it fixed.